# JavaScript Runtime Error when connecting to SQL Server 2014 (Silverlight app in VS2015)

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014

[JavaScript Runtime Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeW32.png)

I have a Silverlight (5) web application that works just fine when connecting to SQL server 2008 database. The db was upgraded to 2014 and then the app won't work anymore. I was rest assured that the db was upgraded just right and I could access and view it in the VS server explorer (also in the ssms). On load, a JavaScript runtime error occurs.

Below is my connection string inside the web config:

```
<add name="Summit"  connectionString="metadata=res://*/DAL.SummitModel.csdl|res://*/DAL.SummitModel.ssdl|res://*/DAL.SummiModel.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string=&quot;
data source=summitdevdb; initial catalog=summit;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Wonder why it works just fine with the previous db but not with the new one.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend copy-paste your connection string to your question (not as a png)

Comment: Are you sure that connection String is valid?